# MMenu remove div

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm using jQuery.mmenu https://mmenu.frebsite.nl. My menu looks like this (Desktop menu):

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation list-inline d-flex justify-content-center">

        <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <div class="list-inline d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col navigation-column pt-1 pb-4">
            <h3>Kategoria</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

How can I get (mobile menu) plugin jQuery.mmenu:

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation list-inline d-flex justify-content-center">

        <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            <h3>Kategoria</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Please help. I've been trying 2 days but I can not improve it.

Comment: it would be helpful if you post a running snippet of your problem

Comment: my desktop menu has <div>...</ div>

How do I run mmenu does not work subcategory style.

Before the <div> in the jQuery.mmenu plugin submenu does not work.

I want the desktop menu to work with a div, but if I use mmenu, I will delete the div.

Please see the demo of my menu http://easyserwer.nazwa.pl/mmenu

Comment: what is wrong with the above demo ?? i can see that subcategory is working fine.

Comment: It does not work in sub-categories. This is caused by <div>. Please look http://easyserwer.nazwa.pl/mmenu/1.jpg